# Why would someone use same id for multiple divs in a single page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I noticed on youtube that replies to each comment are inside a `<div id="replies">`. So the same `id` is used for every comment reply group.

When is it a good practice to give same ids to multiple similar elements?

I know `id`s should be unique, that's why I'm wondering about this.

To check it, go to a youtube video, inspect and select the reply area of a comment. Optionally, `Ctrl+F` in inspect and search `replies`.

[image]

Comment: The two most likely explanations for this are sloppy coding, or deliberate violation of standards. Google is known for the latter - just look at all the non-standard elements and attributes. As you may have guessed, there is never a situation in which this can be considered good practice.

Answer (score 4):

YouTube uses web components which might be the reason there are multiple of the same IDs. Web components are encapsulated chunks of HTML, javascript, and CSS that you can drop into your pages. You can read more about them here: https://www.polymer-project.org/

So my thinking of why YouTube specifically has multiple of the same ID is that the replies component itself has an ID of replies and is being targeted on a component level rather than a global.

I hope this makes sense? Even if it doesn't, try to avoid ID's that aren't unique like the others mentioned.

Comment: More than one ID is invalid HTML no matter the reason.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but as mentioned their reasoning internally was probably in that they were not styling/scripting something they saw as in global scope.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reason YouTube can have duplicate IDs, completely invalid looking html and still get away with it, it's because they are generating dynamic content. Remember, even though it is incorrect, the browser will render it just fine. **They are not using the ID to mark a unique element, but more as metadata.**

Note that Youtube uses custom html tags that I assume helps them reuse code for not just the website, but also for their app.

[Read more about custom elements](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)

**Update:** Just wanted to show an example on how generating content through an application can help you get away with things that could otherwise be a problem.

Writing Inline css is not recommended mainly because it becomes impossible to maintain the larger the css becomes. However, you can code it in an external file during development, then compile it to be inline using an application and have none of the headaches.

[See example](http://idiallo.com/blog/removing-external-css-files)

Comment: Multiple ID can and do cause problems when styling using the same ID. Invalid markup is an error and errors are problems and metadata has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You are right, it can, but if the CSS is generated by an application that automatically keeps track, it doesn't cause them problems.

Comment: An attribute posted to the browser which the questioner has seen means there is an error in the markup. Whether some JS takes care of this later or not is too late. The browser has already rendered the page.

Comment: @Rob: The only thing that can't be changed after page load is the source markup. There is nothing stopping JS from removing/replacing elements or attributes to get rid of any rendering errors (or create more) after the fact.

Comment: @BoltClock Absolutely and that's what I said. The markup is already there and served by the server. It's still invalid.

Comment: @Rob I think you should try it on the browser. Create multiple tags with identical IDs and then define CSS for it. CSS does not care if an id is unique or not, it will style it. As far as we are concerned, it is only invalid in the w3 standard recommendation. It's not recommended to break the rule in case something changes in the future, but if breaking the rule makes your page work better, then why not? The web as we see it today is the results of breaking the rule.

Comment: @ibu I have not heard anyone talk like that in years. "It works" is the lowest common denominator of an excuse to use a piece of code or markup that I can think of. No intelligent programmer would ever use invalid code or markup that "works" at the moment and proceeds in the hope that it never breaks despite warnings from the browser vendors, the standards, and any reasonable programmer worth his salt. If you had a broken calculator that said 2+2=9, but that makes your equation work, I would hate to have you designing the airplane I fly on. The web is based on standards, not hope and prayer.

Comment: I think your metaphor does not hold up. duplicate id is not the same as `2+2=9` it's more like `2+2+2+2+1=9` instead of `5+4=9`. [Also I am sorry, but you might enjoy this page source.](http://idiallo.com/nobot.php)